# not able to parse tags using sax parser

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

Following is my xml:

```
 <Body>
  <tag1 xmlns=""> <innerTag></innerTag> </tag1>
  </Body>
```

The problem is that I am not able to get the string inside `<tag1></tag1>`, that is  **`<innerTag></innerTag>`**. Following is my logic:

```
public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName,
            final String qName, final Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        if ("tag1".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)){
            inTag1 = true;
            System.out.println("start");
        }
}


public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName,
            final String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("tag1".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
            System.out.println("end");
            inTag1 = false;
        }
}

public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length) {

        if (inTag1) {
            System.out.println("@@@" + new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }
}
```

But it is giving me empty output. Can anyone help.

Comment: `innerTag` is an element not a string or a text node. If you want to print it, you will have to do it in the `startElement` and `endElement` callback.

Comment: The `<innerTag>` will be dealt with by `startElement` (and the closing tag by `endElement`, just print `qname` in the else-part of your condition). So the `characters` handler won't see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment to UVM's answer you wrote

> Actually inner tag is a kind of xml inside this xml. So I want that as a whole

There is no way to tell the SAX parser to not process all of the XML inside an element and return the entire contents as a string.  Essentially, you have two options:

- reconstruct the XML string, by listening out to all of the SAX events and building the XML string up yourself, or
- if you're in control of the XML documents you're attempting to parse, changing the format of them to something like

  ```xml
  <Body>
    <tag1 xmlns=""><![CDATA[ <innerTag></innerTag> ]]></tag1>
  </Body>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `"innerTag"` intead of `"tag1"`

```
if ("innerTag".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)){
            inTag1 = true;
            System.out.println("start");
        }
```

Basically your innerTag is a  child element of tag1.So SAX parser keep on parsing because for it, it is till a valid XML element.

Comment: Actually inner tag is a kind of xml inside this xml. So I want that as a whole.

Comment: You will not get it like that because SAX parser in event based parsing.If at all if you want then, you will have to do it manually.In the above code, if parser sees this innertag , then you need to construct it xml string by yourself